# Why was Ser Alliser Thorne sent to the Wall?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

During Robert's Rebellion, so many houses aligned themselves with the current King. However, to the best of my knowledge, none of their heads are sent to the wall. Most of the people fighting for the Crown are pardoned and some of them even retained their former seats, like Barristan Selmy.

What makes Ser Alliser Thorne special and were there anyone else who are sent to the wall after the rebellion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because for one reason or another Tywin Lannister was "annoyed" and offered him a choice... take the black or die...

> [Jeor Mormont] Ser Alliser is an anointed knight, one of the few to take the black since I have been Lord Commander. He fought bravely at King's Landing.
>
> [Jaremy Rykker] On the wrong side. I ought to know, I was there on the battlements beside him. Tywin Lannister gave us a splendid choice. Take the black, or see our heads on spikes before evenfall. No offense intended, Tyrion.
>
> [Tyrion Lannister] None taken, Ser Jaremy. My father is very fond of spiked heads, especially those of people who have annoyed him in some fashion. And a face as noble as yours, well, no doubt he saw you decorating the city wall above the King's Gate. I think you would have looked very striking up there.
>
> <sub>*A Game of Thrones, Chapter 21, Tyrion III*</sub>

Comment: I am more interested in the reason, if we know it.

Comment: @C.Koca  because he was annoyed.... that's all i can find

Comment: Thank you for your effort though. Maybe that is the answer.

Comment: The reason is there. They were enemies on the battlefield. Upon victory, Tywin gave them a choice, die or take the black...

Comment: Remember that Robert is the one famous for forgiving enemies: the Lords of the Reach who besieged his home, inviting Selmy to his Kingsguard, pardoning Balon moments after his rebellion was quashed, forming close ties with the Lannisters who were neutral until the last minute...   Thorne was sent to the wall by Tywin, and Rykker's dialogue suggests this choice was made quickly, probably before Robert was even at King's Landing.